# Check fragment is presented in framelayout or not in android?

Tags: android, fragment, android-framelayout

Hi friends I have two framelayout in movies.xml namely **container**, **detail_screen**.In container will add **movies.xml** which contains listview ,and in detail_screen will have expandable listview called  **movie_details.xml**.Now want to check programatically in detail_screen is already fragment presented or not.if presented just want remove that fragment.I did by follwing and its working fine.

```
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment") != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment")).commit();
}
```

but is there any other way to find whether fragment is presented or not in frame layout in android by programatically .Thanks in advance

Comment: Without using findFragmentByTag()/Id

Comment: You wish to know if a fragment is present without having a reference to it or to its container? There is `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()` which retrieves a list of fragments for that manager.

Comment: @kmg i wish to check if already fragment presented in my framelayout just want to remove that fragment add new fragment otherwise same fragment will be added more than once right

Comment: well if you're using         `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace()` it will replace or add - you don't have to worry about removing an existing fragment

Comment: @sugan.s replace() wont fit in your case?

Comment: yes in my case it won't help @Siddhesh

Comment: Udacity Project ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I founded the solution as follows.i.e before adding any fragments to details_screen just checking if already fragment is presented then popping it and then will add the new fragment.

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_screen) != null) {

        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

            } //to do add fragment
```

hope it will work.

Answer (score 8):

You *have* to use `findFragmentByTag()` or `findFragmentById()` methods to find it. If returned instance is not null, then the fragment is present. Additionally you can use [`Fragment.isInLayout()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isInLayout%28%29) method to check whether fragment was defined in layout using `<fragment>` tag or added programmatically.