# How to switch between fragments without overlapping?

Tags: android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

So i was using SwipeRefreshLayout and Fragments for a simple app that i am working on and i have three files:
1.app_bar_main.xml which contains a FrameLayout which is a container for the fragments heres the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.surafel.tryingfragment.MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        >

    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

2.fragment_main.xml which contains components of the main fragment and a SwipeRefreshLayout heres the code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/refreshMainContent"
    tools:context="com.example.surafel.tryingfragment.MainFragment">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MAIN"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:id="@+id/buttonmain"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

3.MainFragment.java this is the java code for the fragment_main.xml heres the code

```
//i have imported all the necessary classes
public class MainFragment extends Fragment  implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeView;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
        swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.refreshMainContent);
        swipeView.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark),getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark),getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light),getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));

    swipeView.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        return layout;
    }

    public void onRefresh() {
    Log.d("Refreshing","The refresh is working");

    }

}
```

4.i also have MainActivity.java which manages the fragment transactions here the code:
  -when a menu item is selected it passes a position for the setFragment method and the method takes care of it using the switch statement

```
private void setFragment(int position) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mainFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                GradesFragment gradesFragment = new GradesFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, gradesFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
        }

    }
```

when the program starts the main fragment loads and everthing works fine like switching between fragments but when i start refreshing the main fragment
the refresher appears but when i switch to grades fragment while its refreshing it overlaps the two fragments the grades fragment will appear under the main fragment.
but when i wait for the refresh to complete and switch the fragments it works fine.
i tried to stop refereshing when the grades fragment is visible but it doest seem to solve the problem.
So can anyone please help me,i posted all the code because i thought it could be usefull,Thanks.
 [image: this is the screenshot]

Comment: please check is the fragment is available on your framelayout or not. If is contains the fragment then you have to replace it otherwise you have to add new fragment.

Comment: Yes its available it works fine without refreshing

Comment: you have not put condition for check is framelayout contains fragment or not ? so first of all put that condition like 
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445264/' and if return no fragment on framelayout then you have to use fragmentTransaction.add otherwise fragmentTransaction.replace..

Comment: the problem is still there...have you tried it on your computer? Maybe if i am doing something wrong...or can you point me to some other solution for this problem to use swiperefreshlayout with fragments and navigationdrawer please

Comment: Actually no i have not tried on my computer but it's suggestion,  can you please put your screenshot ?

Comment: I have edited my question with a screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130373/discussion-between-rujul-gandhi-and-surafel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in onDestroy() or onPause(). It will work for you.

```
 @Override
 public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
     if (swipeRefreshLayout != null) {
          swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
          swipeRefreshLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
          swipeRefreshLayout.clearAnimation();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Those are methods of the activity right?i am kind of new to android programming

Comment: @surafel Glad to hear you found your solution!